# Read xml data using XDocument class

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file say (test.xml)

```
<root loc-ver="1.0">
  <data name="String1" xml:space="preserve">
        <value loc="root_data_value_2">Description number1</value>
    </data>
  <data name="String2" xml:space="preserve">
        <value loc="root_data_value_3">Description number 2</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

Now, if

I specify the name = "String1", I should get the value as "Description number1"

I specify the name = "String2", I should get the value as Description number2

I am trying with the approach, by no result

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\test.xml");
 string search = "String10";

 var lv1s = from lv1 in doc.Descendants("data")
            select lv1.Name;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
string name = "String1"; // Or whatever
var query = from data in doc.Descendants("data")
            where (string) data.Attribute("name") == name
            select (string) data.Element("value");

string description = query.First(); // Or FirstOrDefault etc
```

You should consider what you want to happen if there isn't exactly one result. Is that an error state (if so, use `Single()`), should you use all the results (if so, just iterate over `query`), should you use the first result if it's available, and ignore it otherwise (if so, use `FirstOrDefault()` and check if the result is null), should you use the first result, and it's an error if there aren't any (if so, use `First()`).